# Using keypress event in knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to read the contents of an html textbox and fetch data from an API to accomplish a google style auto complete. I'm using `twitter bootstrap typeahead` for the auto complete functionality. For that I need to record keys as they are pressed and make the API call with the query text.

The html for the text box is this

```
<input id="query" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keypress', event: { keypress: check }"/>
```

My assumption was that this will update the value in the viewmodel as soon as the key is pressed, and the `check` function will meanwhile call into the API. But the call is made to check( ) and the text box never gets populated when the user types. if the JS looks like this -

```
function check() {
    alert("Hello");     
    }
```

For every key I press, hello pops up but the text box in the HTML UI does not show the key that was pressed/does not record which key was pressed. How do I record the key press and send the request simultaneously?

Comment: use `keyup` instead of `keypress`

Comment: It also works with `keypress` just return `true` from your handler: `function check() {
    alert("Hello");
    return true;     
    }`

Comment: can you post jsfiddle example?

Comment: Thanks @TusharGupta! You could have scored 25 easy points with this one. I didn't know about keyup as I was following this - http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html. And it does not state keyup event.

Comment: @divyanshm i think tushar helped , you he should post the answer now and be marked as answer.

Comment: This is old thread and just to update who ever visits this, just use 
`<input data-bind="textInput : variableName" `
The answer by Kevin M should be acceptable.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1. make sure query is an observable
2. use `valueUpdate = 'afterkeydown'`
3. use `event: { 'keyup': check }:`

Also I'd use console.log if possible as opposed to alert, and log the query so you can make sure the value is updating. :) you also my want to log the event like this

```
function check(data, event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

that will tell you the keycode for the key you pressed

Comment: `event.keyCode` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 35):

This thread is old, but I've noticed it doesn't cite use of KO's **textInput** binding. This is a new feature added in v3.2.0.

The KO docs, at least as of now (Jan-2015), specifically addresses this issue:

#### Note 1: textInput vs value binding

*Although the value binding can also perform two-way binding between text boxes and viewmodel properties, you should prefer textInput whenever you want immediate live updates.*

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html

Comment: Thanks for keeping the thread updated Kevin! This might help someone. :)

Comment: I know it helped me

Comment: Thanks for saving my day